# How to substract multidimensional array in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```
n = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7, 10], [8], [9], [7, 10]]
```

I want to substract all of them with 1. So the result will be:

```
result = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 9], [7], [8], [6, 9]]
```

Comment: Consider getting [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). It does matrix math much better than using lists of lists.

Comment: @user2357112 Numpy is good in general, but it doesn't really work for this particular case - since the nested lists are different lengths, `np.array(n)` gives an array with dtype=object rather than int, and so `np.array(n) - 1` is a TypeError (whereas if they were the same size, it would be exactly the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of lists for sure, use a nested list comprehension:

```
In [13]: result = [[e-1 for e in i] for i in n]

In [14]: print result
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 9], [7], [8], [6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in n:
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        x[i] = y - 1
```

This is more efficient, spacewise at least.

or if you want to use nested list comprehension like zhangxaochen did but assign it to the same value so it does it in place:

```
n[:] = [[b - 1 for b in a] for a in n]
```

Note that this actually still creates two extra lists so it has the same space complexity as assigning it to a new array.

Answer (score 1):

```
result=n
for a in range(len(n)):
    for b in range(len(n[a])):
        result[a][b]=n[a][b]-1
```

Comment: `result=n` just makes the rest of this the same as assigning into `n`. Presumably you meant result should be a deep copy of n, which would have to be `result = [m[:] for m in n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `map()`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> n = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7, 10], [8], [9], [7, 10]]
>>> map(lambda x: map(lambda y: operator.sub(y, 1), x), n)
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 9], [7], [8], [6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def difference(a, n):
    try:
        return a - n
    except TypeError:
        return [difference(i, n) for i in a]

>>> difference([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7, 10], [8], [9], [7, 10]], 1)
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6, 9], [7], [8], [6, 9]]
>>> difference([3, [1, 9, [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]]], [2], [[3, 4], [5, 6]], [3], [7, 10]], 1)
[2, [0, 8, [0, 1, [2, 3, [4, 5]]]], [1], [[2, 3], [4, 5]], [2], [6, 9]]
```

It works for all multidimensional lists.